# How to sync two disks - continually?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, sshfs

I have to HDD drives on two different servers that I need to sync regularly. Until now, I've been using rsync over sshfs, first from one to the other, then from the other to the first, but this method is proving unsatisfactory. When a file is removed from drive A, it is not copied to drive B, but then copied from drive B to drive A. So I can never remove anything unless I do it from both drives. The same goes for renaming - renaming a directory on one drive soon results in two directories with different names but the same contents.

Ideally I need something that keeps track of changes on one drive and then duplicates these changes on the other. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need two separate disk drives?  Why not just use a network-shared file system such as NFS?

Comment: "_`rsync` over `sshfs`_" is a terrible idea. If you want to use `rsync` just use it between the two systems directly - it can use `ssh` natively

Comment: Have you considered (the non-GUI version of) `unison`?

Comment: Do the two servers have a short, fast network path between them (e.g. on the same LAN, not on the other side of the world over the internet using [RFC1149](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1149))?   If so, you could set up a network RAID-1 array using [DRBD](https://www.drbd.org/).

Comment: ok, looks like `DRBD` has been corporatised (but still GPLv2 free software), and the overview page is now https://linbit.com/drbd/

Comment: @AndrewHenle I want my files on two separate disks for backup. Are you suggesting I use NFS instead of sshfs? Besides increased speed, what would be the benefits?

Comment: @OZ1SEJ If you're syncing all changes, you're just reimplementing RAID-1.  if you need backups, do real ***backups***.  What you're doing is not a backup - if you succeed in fully synchronizing all changes including deletes, when someone accidentally deletes everything, your mirroring will reliably replicate that loss of all data.

Comment: @roaima I didn't know that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hmm, what do you mean, "real" backups?

Comment: [OCFS2](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/) is another option to DRBD. Also corporate (Oracle) but GPL2. I haven't used it for about 10 years, though, so my experiences of it will be wildly out of date.

Comment: @OZ1SEJ By "real" backups, I mean [real backups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup).  See [**Why is RAID not a backup?**](https://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup)  Your disk-syncing scheme is just mirroring - and to quote one answer that I linked:  "If you accidentally overwrite your PhD thesis with garbage, redundancy ensures that you have multiple copies of garbage, in case one gets bad. A backup ensures that you can restore your PhD thesis."

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford having a third server storing the files you could use Nextcloud. (You could also host it in one of those servers themselves if there's not a third place available).

In my experience it works well tracking changes from multiple places unless you have some machines on and others off at the same time; in such case, file diff conflicts start appearing easily.

It seems that this question in ServerFault might be a best fit, though: https://serverfault.com/questions/924294/master-master-file-sync-between-datacenters

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Syncthing?
It can continually sync files and if your two devices can communicate directly, you don't even need a relay server as they can sync directly.

https://syncthing.net/